# Use ASCII code to encrypt a message

Tags: c++, ascii

The question requires to output the input following the rules below:

```
1. if the input character is between A-Z, or a-z, the out put character would be
   the following letter, abc-->bcd
2. if the input is Z or z, the output would be A or a,  z->a,Z->A
3. if the input is space, then it remains the same
4. if the input is anything else, increment its ascii value by 1, and print.
```

This is an example:

```
input:  abcZ ]     
output: bcdA ^
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{//use ASCII to get a code for input by changing a to b, b to c....z to a, space remain the same, everything else ++
    char c,d;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if (('A' <= (c=cin.get()) < 'Z')||('a' <= (c=cin.get()) < 'z'))
        {
            d=c+1;

        }
        else if(c=cin.get()==32)// ascii value of space is 32
            d=c;
        else if((c=cin.get())=='Z')
            d='A';
        else if((c=cin.get())=='z')
            d='a';
        else
        {
            c++;
            d=c;
        }
        cout<<d;

    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

What I am thinking is that `♂` is the output of enter key, but I dont want an output for enter key.
space,Z and z don't convert properly either.

Can anyone help me with the code?Thank you.

Comment: I suggest calling `cin.get()` once per loop at the top and testing against the stored value instead of in each if statement.  Otherwise, every time you fail an if statement, you will test against the next letter.

Comment: This isn't even poor encryption, it's just broken: `@` and `Z` both map to `A`, so how do you decrypt `A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a bunch of problems here.  Here are some hints:

1) Call `cin.get()` just once per loop iteration.  That is:

```
for (...)
{
   c = cin.get();
   // do not call cin.get() beyond this point.
   // use the c variable instead

   ...
}
```

2) Be careful around your compound conditionals.

Instead of: `('A' <= c < 'Z')`, you really want: `('A' <= c && c < 'Z')`

3) Add another condition to check for 10.  This is the code for the line feed character.  If this is detected, just do a `cout << endl`

There are a number of ways to simplify the logic here too.  Keep trying!